# Datatables columnDefs setting visible to false has no effect

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using Datatables 1.10.16 and according to the documentation I should be able to set the `columnDefs.visible` property to `false` and that column will not show up (I'm not using responsive). The thing I'm doing a little differently from the examples is that I'm trying to hide a column that is generated from combined data from other columns, but is not an actual data field. Here's my column defn:

```
columnDefs: [
            {
                targets: 'never',
                name: 'sr',
                title: 'SR',
                visible: false,
                searchable: true,
                data: null,
                render: function(data, type, row) {
                    return 'hi';
                },
                className: 'never'
            }
        ]
```

and the corresponding column data (I've been trying several permutations of these settings, (like setting the target to the column index), hence the duplication:

```
columns: [
    {
            name: 'status',
            title: 'Status',
            data: null,
            render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                return 'hello';
            },
            visible: false,
            className: 'never'
        }
```

the column will show up with 'hello', but will not be hidden.

Comment: similar issue here but mine doesn't display when visible:true is set